# Bootstrap Switch Return value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have my checkbox and using Asp.net MVC

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Confirmations" id="Confirmations" checked="@Model.Confirmations" data-size="small" />
```

But when I toggle it(true) and post back the checked value is still false, how do I capture the value on postback (im passing back my model)?

Answer (score 1):

By default bootstrap switch will return a text result not a boolean, true = "on", false="off"
I've change my model to string value which now capturers "on" and then do a conversion in the controller, prob a better way to do this, but seems to work